# Mongoose Model find running into timout but collection query is working

Tags: node.js, docker, mongoose

I was working on the jest tests of our application when suddenly mongoose stopped working. The application and tests run in docker container and have for a long time. Mongoose can establish the connection and can query the database when using `mongoose.connection.collection("users").findOne()` but it failes when using the `User` model in this case, for example `User.findOne()`.

The model works in the main application and these tests also seem to work on collegues PCs with the same setup. I tried to recreate the docker images from scratch, using `docker system prune`, manually deleting all images and volumes, deleting `~/.docker` many times without any success. I hope someone can point me in the right debugging direction to find the flaw.

Example Code I tried for debugging:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import User from '../models/User.mjs';

describe('Debug', () => {

  test('test DB', async () => {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/test", {});
    console.log("Ready state: " + mongoose.connection.readyState);
    console.log(await mongoose.connection.collection("users").findOne());
    console.log(User);
    console.log(await User.findOne());
    await mongoose.disconnect();
  })

})
```

Users model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'mongoose-bcrypt'

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...fields-omitted
}, { timestamps: true })

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

The console output:

```
pptruser@b6cad840e3ca:/app$ npm test -- debug.test.js

> debug-test@1.0.0 test
> JEST_PUPPETEER_CONFIG=tests/jest-puppeteer.config.cjs node --experimental-vm-modules ./node_modules/.bin/jest --detectOpenHandles --runInBand "debug.test.js"

(node:2647) ExperimentalWarning: VM Modules is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
  console.log
    Ready state: 1

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/debug.test.js:8:13)

  console.log
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("629dcc09a5c0753289a9e83a"),
      type: 'User',
      phoneNumber: '+1111111111',
      phoneNumberVerified: false,
      firstname: 'John',
      lastname: 'Doe',
      email: 'john.doe@test.at',
      username: '',
      provider: '',
      authToken: '',
      token: 'mDiQrWKFIPXO3VfvHbToAaEg',
      failedAuthCounter: 0,
      birthDate: 1950-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
      rights: [],
      expireToken: 2022-06-06T09:42:33.155Z,
      createdAt: 2022-06-06T09:42:33.156Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-06-06T09:42:33.156Z,
      __v: 0
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/debug.test.js:9:13)

  console.log
    Model { User }

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/debug.test.js:10:13)

 FAIL  tests/debug.test.js (5.59 s)
  Debug
    ✕ test DB (5001 ms)

  ● Debug › test DB

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      4 | describe('Debug', () => {
      5 |
    > 6 |   test('test DB', async () => {
        |   ^
      7 |     await mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/test", {});
      8 |     console.log("Ready state: " + mongoose.connection.readyState);
      9 |     console.log(await mongoose.connection.collection("users").findOne());

      at tests/debug.test.js:6:3
      at tests/debug.test.js:4:1

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.641 s, estimated 6 s
Ran all test suites matching /debug.test.js/i
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout to rule out that the code before `User.findOne()` isn't just taking _almost_ 5 seconds to complete?

Comment: Yes, also if I use the callback in `User.findOne((user, err) => console.log(user))` I get a timeout from mongoose itself not from jest. Even if I just leave the `User.findOne()` in this test the error persists.

Comment: How long does the connect call take?

Comment: I just took the time, 50ms

Comment: No [Mongoose middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) that could be causing the delay?

Comment: No middleware is defined from us and I also tried to query an other collection with the same fault.

Comment: Try turning on [Mongoose debug logging](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#enable_debugging): `mongoose.set('debug', true)`

Comment: Sadly mongoose isn't saying anything more with this option set. I now tried to strip everything jest away and get this error `MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms`. Online I just find references to DNS problems but the other queries and the connection is working...